# Concatenate values in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary and I'd like to concatenate the values of value[0] and a list in value [1]

so

```
dict={       'Key1':['MASTER',['_A','_B','_C']]}
```

and expected output is of calling Key1 is

```
[['MASTER_A','MASTER_B','MASTER_C']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
d = {'Key1':['MASTER',['_A','_B','_C']]}
out = [d['Key1'][0]+i for i in d['Key1'][1]]
```

**Output** :

```
['MASTER_A', 'MASTER_B', 'MASTER_C']
```

To assign it to the key, do :

```
d['Key1'] = out
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a nested comprehension:

```
d = {'Key1':['MASTER',['_A','_B','_C']]}
result_dict = {k: [v[0] + l for l in v[1]] for k,v in d.items()}
```

For example:

```
>>> result_dict = {k: [v[0] + l for l in v[1]] for k,v in d.items()}
>>> result_dict
{'Key1': ['MASTER_A', 'MASTER_B', 'MASTER_C']}
```